# How to add numbers onto the back of an existing number (GUI Calculator)

Tags: java

So for school I need to make a GUI calculator, I have fully made the calculator working, but only up to single digit arthmatic (1+1) but now I wish to make it that that I can have multiple digits inputed (123 + 45) this is my code:

```
b1.addActionListener(e -> {System.out.println("Response:1 was inputed onto calculator"); 
                                    if(arth == "") {
                                    num1S = Double.toString(num1);
                                    Tnum1S = "1" + num1S; 
                                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(Tnum1S);
                                    l.setText(Tnum1S); 
                                    Tnum1S = "";
                                    } else {
                                    num2S = Double.toString(num2);
                                    Tnum2S = num2S + "1"; 
                                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(Tnum2S);
                                    l.setText(Tnum2S); 
                                    Tnum2S = "";
                                    }});
                                    //T at the start means Temporary, S at te end means a String, normally my numbers are set to double.
```

This is a screenshot of my results from my try of making this work[image] does anyone know how to make it that the number is not added into the decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#"); // you can change it here

System.out.println(format.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the line `Tnum1S = "1" + num1S;` , you are essentially concatenating 1 to the content of num1S as a String. Instead, for building a calculator you should be adding them as doubles and then push to the user interface.

num1S contains the String equivalent of num1.

`num1S = Double.toString(num1);`

Tnum1S now gets a 1 concatenated with num1S.

`Tnum1S = "1" + num1S;`

You are now converting the concatenated value ( not added value )back to Double

`num1 = Double.parseDouble(Tnum1S);`

You are finally setting it on the UI.

`l.setText(Tnum1S);`

Instead you should,

1. Convert the numbers of your interest from String to Double.
2. Perform the operation as a Double.
3. Push the result back to the user interface as a String.

In short, in your case, you are using the concatenation operation on String rather than the addition operation on a double.

Comment: So I tried this out, but it isn't the outcome I need, as all it is doing is just + like (2+1)

Comment: Yes, that what was I intended to. Can you please give a sample example and the expected output in your question so that it is clear.

Comment: I would like it so that I can use 2,3 or 4 digit numbers (example: 106 * 945) in my calculatoins, currently all I can do is single digit like (1 * 9).  but whith my current code if I try to do so it places the new numbers (as seen in the screen shot) as the least significant decimal place